# Why is $.isEmptyObject not valid here

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        var data = [{"date_range": $("#date").val()},
                    {"day_of_week":  $("#day_of_week").find('option:selected').text()},
                    {"call_volume": $("#call_volume").find('option:selected').text()},
                    {"number_of_calls": $("#number_of_calls").val()}]

        var info = data.filter(function(item) {return $.isEmptyObject(item)})
        alert(info)
    })
```

what is wrong with the code above?

basically what im trying to do is filtering for objects that are not empty in the data array.

I mean the criteria for something to pass through `filter` is it should be true right?

so why isn't the code above working?

alert info is always empty despite most objects in the data array are not empty

Comment: Where are the empty objects?

Comment: Your array has no empty objects; your filter keeps *only* empty objects - so yes, `info` will always be an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to negate the result of `$.isEmptyObject(object)`,

```
var info = data.filter(function(item) {return !$.isEmptyObject(item)});
```

Since, if the passed object is not an empty one, then `isEmptyObject` will return `false`, And you are returning it in the `callBack` of `filter`. So all the elements in the array are ignored.

This is how `Array.prototype.filter` works,

```
var keepIt = true;
var sample = [1,2,3,4].filter(function(){ 
              return keepIt; //It will be true always, 
                             //so all the items will be preserved. 
                             //If it is false, then all the elements will be ignored.
             });
```

Comment: wow thats because is empty object checks if the object is empty and then returns false if it isn't fml :/

but it's still odd though. one of the objects was empty but it wasn't returned. anyway this helped thank you

Comment: "isempty" checks if it's empty and returns "yes" if it *is* empty, ie it tells you it's  empty - how is that "fml" or odd?   Why would you expect that if ask if it's empty and it is empty then you get back a "no"?

Comment: @freedomn-m I guess thats what happens when your coding at 1 am in the morning after work coding for 8 hours. Seriously I was like wtf was I thinking